# Android widget can't receive the DATE_CHANGED message

Tags: android, date, android-intent, widget

I am developing a calendar widget, and I can't receive the DATE_CHANGED message when I changed the date **MANUALLY**.

What is the problem?

My code in Manifest is :

```
<receiver android:name="com.widget.calendar.CalendarWidgetProvider">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- This specifies the widget provider info -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
</receiver>
```

And I tried to receive it like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED")) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Date changed.....!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    super.onReceive(ctx, intent);
}
```

But the log is not print when I change the system date manually.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I solved this with [Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED), It's really a bug of DATE_CHANGED.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this intent:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

And receive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.TIME_SET")) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Date changed.....!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    super.onReceive(ctx, intent);
}
```

Comment: but this will cause drain your battery as it will call broadcast reciever again and again whenever time will change.

Comment: @Akki I've tested that It will not send this TIME_SET intent unless I change the system Time or Date manually. So the battery is safe here.:)

Comment: so you want to call this reciever when user change the date manually?

Comment: @Akki Yes, I am doing a Calendar widget now. :)